# Using "puts" vs "return" in Ruby method

Tags: ruby

**Edited** to better state the question:

I am writing a method to convert a number into a string in english. For example: 888 would be converted to "eight hundred and eighty eight".

Which of both options should I use and why?

Option A (using "puts" inside function):

```
def convert_number_to_english number

    <code>

    puts number_in_english
end

convert_number_to_english 888
```

Option B (using "return" inside function and later using "puts" before calling function):

```
def convert_number_to_english number

    <code>

   return number_in_english
end

puts convert_number_to_english 888
```

Comment: In what situation? Don't say that the code tells that. It does not say anything. Explain it in words.

Comment: Hi Sawa, I am a beginner and I am doing an exercise from a book: to create a method that takes a number and transforms the number into a string in English language. There is more code later to also convert the amount of tens and units. But that's it, just a student trying to resolve a simple exercise. Sorry there is not much more than this.

Comment: In the event that you change your code in future, and have some other use for `numberInEnglish`, you're better off with `B`. You don't need `return` in `B`; `numberinEnglish` is enough, as Ruby returns the last value calculated if there is no explicit `return`.  As a matter of convention, Rubyists do not use `return` when it is not needed, and use "snake-case" , rather than "camel-case" for names of methods and variables, so would here write `convert_number_to_english` and `number_in_english`.

Comment: When you give examples, make them as short as is necessary to make the point.  Also, the specific code in your example is not important and will not be executed by readers, so you can just indicate where there is some code.  Here you could write A: `def my_method; <code to compute my_var> puts my_var; end`. and B: `def my_method; <code to compute my_var> my_var; end; puts my_var`.

Comment: Thanks, Cary, nice advice. Is it ok if I edit me question now to do it like you said?

Comment: Yes. In general, you cannot change a question, and if your edit corrects the question or adds additional information, you should indicate that it's an edit (e.g., "Edit: ..."), but here you are doing neither of those things, so I believe you can just restate the question without mentioning that it's an edit. If any readers disagree with this advice, please say so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, I try to keep my code 'pure'. By 'pure', I mean no additional side effects.

In this specific case your function, based on its name, is asking for a number and returning an english readable string representation of the given number. I would avoid doing any IO (`puts`, `File.open`, etc, which are considered side effects) within this function. I would go with the `return` variation.

If your function had been called something like `print_converted_number`, I would say that it would be okay to have `puts` instead of `return`.

Basically what I am saying is that you should name your functions with what they actually do.

**Note**: In Ruby, you can generally leave out the `return` from most functions. In Ruby, a function will automatically return the last thing evaluated.

Comment: Thanks @Justin Wood, very concise and clear explanation.